# Excel 1004 - Are the Domain Userrights the cause of my Problems?

Tags: excel, vba

We are using a central Makro.xlm file and some Workbooks accessing the Makro this way.

```
Workbooks.Open Makro_Path & Makro_Nam, ReadOnly:=True
Application.Run Makro_Nam & "!MakroIni", WbTyp
```

The first line works fine - The Makro Workbook is Opened correctly. The second line gives me an 1004 error: Makro not found or all Makros are disabled.

The interesting part is:

We have 2 completely different domains/networks accessing those files. In our older network everything works fine the newer one creates those troubles.

Normally those files are stored on a central server, but for testing purposes they can be run locally - same result.

Does anyone have an idea, wyh on Pcs in the newer network, the makros are loaded correctly, but can not execute? Is it possible, that some global user rights interfer with the Execution of Excel Macros?

Comment: is every PC using the same version of excel with the same settings? generally network and user rights should stop the first line from executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a 64Bit version of Excel in the new network.